# How to strip part of a string in dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'Country - USA': 'Approved',
'Country - Italy': 'Approved'}
```

I want to remove the from it `Country -`  string.
The output should be:

```
{'USA':'Approved',
'Italy':'Approved'}
```

I tried to use dict.items() somehow but I didn't succeed

Comment: Please post the code you tried so we can help you with it. Please also post the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: Try this out : `{key.split(" ")[-1]:val for key, val in mydict.items()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right trail with `dict.items()`. Here's a dictionary comprehension that will get you what you want:

```
d = {'Country - USA': 'Approved', 'Country - Italy': 'Approved'}
new = {key.split()[-1]:value for key, value in d.items()}
print(new)
```

outputs:

```
{'USA': 'Approved', 'Italy': 'Approved'}
```

We're taking the value of each key, `split`ting it on whitespace (the default argument), and taking the last piece. Of course, this will only work if the country has a 1-word name.

Another option is to simply remove `"Country - "`:

```
{key.lstrip("Country - "):value for key, value in d.items()}
```

or you can go by index:

```
{key[10:]:value for key, value in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with this code

```
x = {'Country - USA': 'Approved', 'Country - Italy': 'Approved'}

index_position = len('Country - ') - 1
x = {key[index_position:]: value for key, value in x.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
str_to_delete = "Country - "
d = {'Country - USA': 'Approved', 'Country - Italy': 'Approved'}
d = {
 country.replace(str_to_delete, ""): value
 for country, value in d.items()
}
print(d)   # {'USA': 'Approved', 'Italy': 'Approved'}
```